# Time spent writing an email with gmail API

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I want to know time spent editig/writing emails to certain recipients. Is it possible to do this via gmail API (or any other way)?

Comment: I highly doubt it. I don't even know if Google tracks that information. You could try to track it yourself by using a user script for the Gmail website.

Answer (score 0):

Currently **`Gmail API`** does not provide any such functionality.
But if you are making your own application using **`Gmail API`** then you can easily achieve this using some **`javascript`** or preferably **`jQuery`**.